# Where can one see the rationale and planning for R version rollouts?

Tags: r, admin

I've been using R for 13+ years, and teaching R for 3+ years, and I still get blind-sighted by the timing and rationale for R's 'x.y.z' midyear releases. For the past few years they have tried to standardize it, with a new 'x.y.0' coming out each year in the spring, and 2-3 'x.y.z' updates during the following year. But the reality has been anything but predictable.

Specifically, for the 2nd year in a row, and the 3rd time in 4 years, the 'x.y.0' release was followed within a month or so by an 'x.y.1' release, ostensibly because there was some major bug or instability in the former. And this year they also released a 3.2.5, only 3 weeks before the 3.3.0. Normally, one would expect each 'x.y.z' release to last 3-4 months before being replaced.

My problem is, I have yet to find the place online where discussions, or at least some authoritative summary, of the issues involved and what R users should expect regarding upcoming releases, are posted. Either I am missing something obvious, or most of this happens somewhere very obscure or even behind closed doors.

To clarify: we do eventually receive a detailed list of all changes that took place in a release. But I cannot find the information regarding what's in the pipeline, whether there are major issues in the current release I should be aware of, etc.

**Or in other words, I'm looking for the "Forest" level view, rather than the "Trees". Does the current release have major issues? If yes, is there a fix in the works and when? Regardless, are there grand changes planned for an upcoming release? Etc.**

Any insight on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Assaf

Comment: Good question. I'd love to have a long-term, big-picture idea of what goals might be in store for 3.4.0 and if there's what sorts of changes and what timelines might eventually make 4.0.0.

Comment: @Gregor How is this a good question? This is just an OT off site tool/library/other request type of question. I don't see how it fits on SO.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of the better ways to stay up-to-date is by following the R-announce [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-announce).  It also has a [web archive](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/) if you find that more convenient.

Furthermore, the [R developer page](https://developer.r-project.org/) seems like a useful resource.  It includes a regularly update [NEWS file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/NEWS.html) with the recent and upcoming changes to R.

Comment: Mr. Llama, thanks for the comment. I'm familiar with R-Devel; it has "tree-level" detail bug lists. I'm looking for a "forest-level" overview of what's going on. The R-announce listserv doesn't seem to be in much use. Versions 3.2.5 and 3.3.1 are not even mentioned there.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify it even more.

Comment: We usually wait on updates til x.y.2 and then remain on that unless there is a feature breaking bug. We monitor https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel for bugs and then just run over the NEWS file if we've missed anything when there is a x.y.2+ release. I don't think there is forrest level stuff since so much of this is so user specific. The closes might be the 'SIGNIFICANT USER-VISIBLE CHANGES' in the NEWS. https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2016/thread.html did have 3.2.5 and 3.3.1 mentioned.